# Interrupt based communication between arduino and raspberry pi

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, interrupt, wiringpi

I have 6 Arduinos and 1 raspberry pi B+.
I need Arduino to communicate with pi based on interrupts. For example, if 1 Arduino has to communicate with pi, it sends interrupt and then pi asks the Arduino to send data. On the other hand, Pi can communicate directly without any interrupt.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't clear my question. My question is, is that possible to have interrupts from arduino to Pi, while having I2C communication or SPI communication?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the Raspberry GPIO pins as Rising/Falling edge interrupts.
[Raspberry GPIO](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#gpio)

Then you can use one of the digital ports in your Arduino to generate Rising or Falling edge so it will trigger the Raspberry interrupt.

If you have several Arduinos and you don't want to waste several Raspberry pins, you can connect all Arduinos to a single GPIO pin of the Raspberry (using pullup resistors so when one Arduino Triggers you will not create a short circuit).

You will then need some kind of protocol for the Raspberry to know which Arduino triggered the Interrupt.

Hope this helps